# How to wait between promises

Tags: javascript, node.js, promise, bluebird

I have a command that returns before fulfilling, so I want to wait a little bit before following the promise chain. Is there any best practice to do so?

```
 new Promise(function (resolve, reject) {
      exec('netbeast new test-app', function (err, stdout, stderr) {
        if (err) return reject(err)
        else return resolve(PATH_TO_APP)
      })
    })
    .then(fs.readdirAsync)
    .then(fs.readFileAsync.bind(fs, PATH_TO_APP + '/server.js'))
    .then(function (data) {
      var shebang = data.toString().slice(0, data.toString().indexOf('\n'))
      shebang.should.equal('#!/usr/bin/env node')
      return Promise.resolve()
    })
    .then(fs.readJsonAsync.bind(fs, PATH_TO_APP + '/package.json'))
    .then(function (data) {
      return fs.accessAsync(PATH_TO_APP + '/' + data.main, fs.X_OK)
    })
    .then(done)
```

Comment: I didn't think async programming had a concept of "waiting"... not in the tradition sense of 'delay' and such.

Comment: Please elaborate. What exactly is the problem?

Comment: The problem basically is that the promises is being executed before the exec command ends.

Comment: Could you try to remove "return Promise.resolve()" after shebang test?

Comment: Waiting for an arbitrary duration of time seems *very* fragile. I can't really believe that the callback passed to exec is executed before the process terminated. The docs say: *"called with the output when process terminates"*. However, if that's really the case you might want to try something else, e.g. `spawn`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It probably can be useful in some use cases where it is convenient to wait a little bit before starting another action. I think the simplest way would be:

```
.then(function() {
    return new Promise(function (resolve) {
         setTimeout(resolve, TIME_TO_WAIT_IN_ms)
    })
})
```

**EDIT:** I do not think there is a "best practice" for this. Waiting, as commented above, is not contemplated in async programming. However I imagine it can be used in edge cases where, as asked, a workaround is needed.

**EDIT 2**: As commented below, bluebird (a promise library) has built-in shortcut for this. For a promise `p.delay(TIME_IN_ms).then(...)` or `p.then(() => return Promise.delay(TIME_IN_ms))`.

Comment: I will try this ;)

Answer (score 4):

> I have a command that returns before fulfilling

If that operation isn't tied to a promise that you can monitor and know when it's done, that sounds like a design mistake.  You should fix your operation so it does not fulfill until the async operation is actually done.  You don't explain exactly where your problem is with this, but if you did, we could probably help you fix the real problem and not put in a delay hack.

If it's a coordination issue between multiple promises, then you probably just need to make sure the various async operations are appropriately chained together so one waits for the previous, either by returning a promise from within a `.then()` handler, returning a promise from a function that allows the caller to wait for completion or appropriately chaining the operations with successive `.then()` handlers.

---

If you really do need to insert a delay, it looks like you are using Bluebird that contains a built-in delay mechanism.  On a given promise `p`, you can use the `.delay(n)` method:

```
p.delay(100).then(...)   // wait 100ms before allowing promise chain to proceed
```

Or, inside a `.then()` handler, you can return `Promise.delay(n)` as in:

```
p.then(function(data) {
   ...
   return Promise.delay(100);  // wait 100ms before allowing promise chain to proceed
})
```

Answer (score 0):

The promise will call the code in `then` only after you call `reject` or `resolve`. If it doesn't behave like that, there's a big problem.

If you want to delay the resolution of the promise, you can delay the call to reject or resolve:

```
  exec('netbeast new test-app', function (err, stdout, stderr) {
    setTimeout( () => {
        if (err) reject(err);
        else resolve(PATH_TO_APP);
    }, 100);
  })
```

I removed the `return` in the callback, since I didn't see why.

Comment: That also works for me in that case! Thank you so much for you response

Comment: I agree about `return`statements. About what concerns the answer, the one above I believe it was more general, but this is effective and lean for the case as well.